# C MySQL Connector - Error 2014 - Commands out of sync when using CALL

Tags: mysql, c, stored-procedures

We are working on an assignment. 
We are currently trying to call a remote procedure in a MySQL database, but we're getting a 2014 Error and we can't figure out why. We should note that the call is successful and we get the results we expect to get, the problem is in the call to `mysql_stmt_close(stmt)`.
We are freeing every MYSQL structure that was generated by the calls to the connector, using `mysql_free_result`, but the error persists. The error is coming from the `mysql_stmt_close(stmt)` call, we're getting a 2014 error, as stated in the title. We are freeing every MYSQL structure possible, as far as we can see.

The code is mostly taken from examples over the Internet:

```
int basedatos_crearUsuario(char * pNombre, MYSQL * pConeccion){
char * query = "CALL crearUsuario (?)";
MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
MYSQL_BIND ps_params[1];  /* input parameter buffers */
MYSQL_BIND bind_results[1];

stmt = mysql_stmt_init(pConeccion);
if (!stmt)
{
    printf("Could not initialize statement\n");
    return -1;
}
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, query, strlen(query))){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (errno: %d)\n",mysql_error(pConeccion), mysql_errno(pConeccion));
    return -1;
}

long largo = (long) strlen(pNombre);
memset(ps_params, 0, sizeof (ps_params));
ps_params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
ps_params[0].buffer = pNombre;
ps_params[0].buffer_length = largo;
ps_params[0].length = &largo;
ps_params[0].is_null = 0;

if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, ps_params)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (errno: %d)\n",mysql_error(pConeccion), mysql_errno(pConeccion));
    return -1;
}
if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (errno: %d)\n",mysql_error(pConeccion), mysql_errno(pConeccion));
    return -1;
}
MYSQL_RES* temp;
if (temp = mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt)) { //
    fprintf(stderr, " mysql_stmt_execute(), 1 failed\n");
    fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
    return -1;
}
MYSQL_RES* aRes = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(stmt);//

MYSQL_FIELD* aField = &(aRes->fields[0]); 
int totalrows = mysql_stmt_num_rows(stmt);

int resultadoQuery;
long largo2 = 0;
memset (bind_results, 0, sizeof (bind_results));
bind_results[0].buffer_type= aField->type;
bind_results[0].is_null= 0;
bind_results[0].buffer= (char *) &resultadoQuery;
bind_results[0].buffer_length= 255;
bind_results[0].length= &largo2;

mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, bind_results);  
while(!mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt)){
    printf("hay result");
}

mysql_free_result(aRes);
mysql_free_result(temp);
if (mysql_stmt_close(stmt)) //HERE: the stmt_close call returns an error.
{
  fprintf(stderr, " usuario failed while closing the statement\n");
  fprintf(stderr, " %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
  exit(0);
}

return resultadoQuery;
```

We would appreciate any insight as to why this would happen. The CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS flag is enabled for the connection, too. We've looked several other similar questions, but we appear to have the flag enabled and the calls in the right order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-store-result.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-next-result.html (probably the most useful link)

Your CALL statement is most likely returning multiple results sets, generally if you run a SELECT that returns data inside the procedure then you get one result set for the query and then a second result set for the procedure execution itself.

You need to advance to that next result set for the procedure, and process it (or throw it away).

I would loop on mysql_next_result and then throw them away after your mysql_free_result and before mysql_stmt_close.

Comment: Indeed. We didn't know that the statement returned two result sets, we were only thinking about the query. Thanks!

Comment: No problems, a common mistake and also SQL Server (many people have experience with it) has an option to suppress the second result set.  MySQL does not.

Comment: The same problem happens if you are using ADO with the MySQL ODBC driver.
If you call RecordSet.MoveNext until RecordSet.EOF is reached, then this bug is gone there too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try to debug your stored procedure also

1. check if in your stored procedure there is select statement returning more than one rows
2. check if in your stored procedure there is a log statement you forgot to delete,i.e. standard output or select 1,select 2 type statement.

   if (temp = mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt))

mysql_stmt_store_result doesnt return MYSQL_RES. probably temp is null